# Web Crawler GUI, JTable Inserts not working & Thread get Methods

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, web-crawler

i have been working on a web Crawler (Data miner) with multiple threads.
I had it work in the console just fine, gathering unique data (seemingly) using Volatiles HashSet and synchronized Threads and methods.

Then i decided to make it a Gui to keep track of what it is doing more easily.

Right now I'm facing multiple problems.

1 ) When I instantiate my threads and start them (I try to insert a row in a        JTable where every row keeps track of the threads stats)....right now I just put in dummy stats and they only show up if I insert them from the main GUI constructor....if I try to add them dynamically when I start my thread (Still dummy stats because of problem #2) they just don't show up. I tried insertRow(), addRow() they all seem to fail when not in the main Gui Constructor.

**** SEE EDIT ****

2) Since my crawler class implements Runnable and I create threads to start them, I don't have access to their get method....is there a way around that ?

Any ideas are welcome thanks in advance.

the code is quite long so I wont post it here but if you need some specific pieces of code I'd be more than happy to provide it !

EDIT : Problem 2 Solved, For problem number 1, now That i solved problem #2 i coudl test the get methods and they do provide the right data, i simply cant get them to show up as rows in the JTable

Comment: 1. `if I try to add them dynamically when I start my thread` be sure you are doing so on the EDT - you can dispatch onto the EDT using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` 2. Not sure what you mean - sounds like a scope issue in that your Runnable needs an instance of Crawler (without code its difficult to advise) 3. I'd recommend first breaking this down into individual and specific questions, then create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the exact issue

Comment: Right now there are 3 classes in my program
- The main one where my volatile Variables are and where i create my gui
- The Crawler itself (that i now change to Extend Threads)
- And the Class that identifies the data i need